# Magento creating a custom template from backend category layout

Tags: magento

I need to create a custom template with products categories. Which means under one category limited number of related products should be displayed. Under another category that category related products should be displayed. Also there should be a label which display those category names. As well as I need to add a link to view more products.

I am doing this through category layout (backend). I added the below code and tried.

```
    <reference name="header">
         <block type="core/template" name="header_nav" as="headerNav" template="page/html/headernav.phtml">
    </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
          <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list_flowers"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml">  
    <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>178</value></action>
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
          </block>

    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list_cakes"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml">  
    <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>179</value></action>
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
          </block>     
    </reference>
```

Category products are displaying. But this is not limiting the number of products. Also the header is not displaying. And I cannot add a link to this page.

Can anyone please help me on this. Thank You.

Comment: <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action> this sets the number of columns to display the products meaning this will show 4 columns in a row. This will not set any limitation to the number of products. To set the limitation, you will need to override app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php ------ _getProductCollection() function.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes that way we can solve this issue. I was thinking whether there is any other way to do with above code.

Comment: Please find the answer posted by me how this can be done

Answer (score 0):

To be able to set limitation on Product Collection (since this differs from category to category in your case), find below the implementation:

```
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="catalog/product_list_flowers" name="product_list_flowers"  template="catalog/product/list/flowers.phtml">  
        <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>178</value></action>
        <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
      </block>

      <block type="catalog/product_list_cakes" name="product_list_cakes"  template="catalog/product/list/cakes.phtml">  
         <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>179</value></action>
         <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
      </block>     
     </reference>
```

The above code will continue to display 4 columns with products.

Create block files (If this differs from category to category)

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Catalog/Product/List/Flowers.php
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Catalog/Product/List/Cakes.php
```

Override **List.php** (If all the categories require same limitation of products)

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Catalog/Product/List.php
```

```
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list_flowers"  template="catalog/product/list/flowers.phtml">  
        <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>178</value></action>
        <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
      </block>

      <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list_cakes"  template="catalog/product/list/cakes.phtml">  
         <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>179</value></action>
         <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
      </block>     
     </reference>
```

Below line no: 87, In this **public function _getProductCollection()**

```
     ...
      $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
       $this->_productCollection->setPageSize(10); //this will display only 10 products
     ...
```

Let me know if I was able to understand it correctly.

Happy Coding...